# Projective family of probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, category-theory

I'm confused about the definition of a projective family of probability spaces $(S_t,\mathscr S _t,\mu_t,f_{ts})$. Let our indexing set be a poset $T$. The conditions

- $f_{tt}=1_{S_t}$
- $f_{us}=f_{ts}\circ f_{ut}$ where $s\leq t\leq u$

are clear from the usual definition of a projective system as a functor from the opposite of a poset category. However, (in addition to measurability) the following condition always appears:

- $\mu_s = (f_{ts})_{\ast}(\mu_t)$, where the RHS is the pushforward measure.

Where exactly does this condition come from? How does the usual categorical definition of a projective system give rise to it? The category I thought of working in has probability spaces as objects and measurable functions as arrows. (Perhaps I'm in the wrong category?) The condition above looks more like a cone condition..

Furthermore, the projective limit (if it exists) is required to satisfy the following tow conditions:

- Its $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the restrictions of the projections $\pi_t$
- Its probability measure $\mu$ must satisfy $(\pi_t)_\ast (\mu)=\mu _t$

Although these make sense, I still don't see how to derive them directly from the abstract definitions.

Comment: Again, I am mystified by the unexplained (as usual) downvote...

Comment: First of all , you need to understand in what category you're working. Your objects are triples $(S, \mathscr{S}, \mu_S)$ and a map between these objects is a  measurable map between the probability spaces  $f: S \rightarrow T$ such that $f_{*}\mu_S = \mu_T$